# Simplenote clients

Tags: applications, simplenote

I recently started using [Simplenote](http://simplenoteapp.com). I want to be able to take and read my notes while on the go. There is a native iOS app, but not for Android.

Are there third-party apps that will sync with Simplenote? What is your experience with it/them?

Comment: @Izzy: Yes, I  know. You'll note that I was one of the people who voted to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplenote is updating all of their apps, and that also means that [they've released an official Android app](http://www.theverge.com/2013/9/9/4713592/simplenote-for-android-now-available).

> The official app doesn't require an account to use; you can take and store notes locally on your device before signing up to the free service for cloud syncing. Although third-party apps were previously available, the official option is a welcome one that gives Android users an experience in line with the iOS app.
>
> Simplenote's expansion to Android comes just over half a year since Wordpress owner Automattic bought the service, pledging to improve its mobile apps.

[Simplenote on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.automattic.simplenote)

Answer (score 2):

1. [mNote](http://www.appbrain.com/app/net.minuo.android.mnote) works well, simple.
2. [AndroNoter](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.cristianca.notes) (never tried it but it is ad free)

Both are free.  I have never used it on an iPhone so I don't have a basis of comparison.  I also don't use Simplenote much anymore because I've consolidated to just Evernote.  I also preferred 3Banana to Simplenote but in the end opted for Evernote.

Comment: I have been using AndroNoter for a couple days now and it works well. mNote gave me a bit of trouble because it didn't like some character in my password. The developer wrote back to me quickly, though, so I'll check it out when there is a new release.

Answer (score 2):

The [Simplenote website actually lists some Android clients](http://simplenoteapp.com/downloads/).  Click the link and scroll down to "mobile", where you'll find 4 or 5 of them listed.

I tried Evernote myself, and had the worst experience.  I have a Droid 2, and the notes were not reliably syncing to my PC.  The Evernote customer service is the worst I've ever experienced in my life.  They don't allow a dialogue with their people.  They close your case before your problem is solved.  It's a real mess.  That's why I'm giving Simplenote a try.

Good luck!

Comment: The page has changed, and the 3rd-party mobile clients are no longer listed. What were they?